# Need help figuring out what I'm doing wrong in my if statement

Tags: c#, winforms, math, if-statement

I'm still learning `C#` with Windows Forms and I would like some help with my if statement.

The variables are fixed so there is going to be no user input other than them just clicking one button. Where my issue begins is at the beginning of the if statement.

VS(Visual Studios) constantly says that the `half` and `calc` in the condition, and the `hours` for the conversion to string are all unassigned local variables.

Then in the else statement where the math equation is, VS keeps saying that "hours" cannot be converted from `double` to `hours`.

I dont know what that means because I already declared them. Then it says the `thirtheenpercent` cannot be declared in the scope because it has already been declared. I dont know why it's saying this because this double is not supposed to change.

Can someone help me and explain why I am getting these errors? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        decimal onecup = 130;
        decimal thirtheenpercent;
        decimal hours=0;
        decimal half=130/2;
        decimal calc=0;

        while (onecup>half)
        {
            thirtheenpercent = (onecup * 13) / 100;
           calc =onecup-thirtheenpercent;
            onecup=calc;
            hours++;
        } mtbHalf.Text = Convert.ToString(hours)+" Hours.";

        while (!(hours==24))
        {
            thirtheenpercent = (onecup * 13) / 100;
            calc = onecup - thirtheenpercent;
            onecup = calc;
            hours++;
        } mtbOnecup24.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(calc,2)) + " mg.";
        //While i was running this program, i ran into some conflictions with my already declared variables for my last while loop so i created some new ones.//
        decimal thirtheenpercent2;
        decimal calc2 = 0;
        decimal onecup2 = 130;
        int hours2 = 0;

        while (!(hours2 == 24))
        {
            thirtheenpercent2 = (onecup2 * 13) / 100;
            calc2 = onecup2 - thirtheenpercent2;
            onecup2 = calc2;
            hours2++;
            onecup2 = onecup2 + 130;
        } mtbQuantity.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(onecup2, 2)) + " mg.";


    }
```

Comment: well, `hours` _is_ unassigned. As far as `half` and `calc` go, maybe you are just misinterpreting the error message.

Comment: And you can't write `hours * thirtheenpercent = calc`. An assignment must involve some storage location on the left; you can't assign some value to an expression.

Comment: Also note that the `double` type is approximate, so you might never hit your `half == calc` condition. You start `half` as 65, and `calc` could end up as `65.0000000001` or `64.99999998` because of how doubles behave - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hours` variable is unassigned, in the code you posted. So that error seems correct to me.

The code example is incomplete, but given what you've posted it does not appear that `half` and `calc` are in fact unassigned. So the most likely explanation for that is that you are either misinterpreting the error message (i.e. it doesn't say what you say it says), or you are not sharing the correct code (i.e. the code you included isn't the code that's being compiled when the error occurs).

As far as the last errors, your program statement `hours * thirtheenpercent = calc` is not valid syntax. The compiler will probably try to interpret that as a variable declaration, where `hours` is the type and the `thirtheenpercent` variable is being declared as a pointer to that type, initialized with the value held by the variable `calc`.

That's clearly not what you meant, and of course since `hours` is not a type, there's no way for the statement to compile successfully.

Possibly you meant `calc = hours * thirtheenpercent`? It's hard to tell from your question.

You seem to have other algorithmic issues. But without seeing the actual specification for what your code is supposed to do, it's hard to know for sure what the code should look like. Based on the comments, it's doubtful the algorithm would ever work as you seem to want it. You start with 13% of 130, and then (maybe) iteratively work through the multiples of that value. But no multiple of 13% is equal to 50%, so no multiple of (13% of 130) can be equal to (50% of 130).

On top of that, as commenter Ed Gibbs says, dealing with floating point, it's entirely possible that `half` and `calc` will *never* equal each other even the algorithm made sense. You could get extremely close, but not where the two values actually compare as identical.

Comment: Thanks man, i completely forgot that i needed to have the "calc" on the left side of the "=". Once i fixed that all of my problems went away  except the "hours" issue. I solved this by making it equal 0 in the beginning. now everything works fine :-) I will edit my code so i can show you what i have done :-D

Comment: btw, this all had to deal with the amount of caffeine that would remain in the body after an hour, then how much would remain after 24 hours if someone had one cup every hour for 24 hours, and then how long it would take until half was left.

Comment: @SprJD7903: interesting problem. The second part of the question is easy, as the half-life of caffeine is a known fact: roughly 5 hours. But it's entertaining to imagine someone who is literally drinking 25 cups of coffee, each cup one hour apart. That's one dedicated coffee drinker. :) Anyway, I'm glad the answer was able to get you back on track.

Comment: Iterative multiplication is a power operation, if you want to reverse it, use a logarithm.  Not sure why you think division would be involved.

Comment: @BenVoigt: because in my head, I translated "multiplication" to "addition", thus arriving at the wrong conclusion for the original word. Oh well...